# How to drop column from the target data frame, but the column(s) are required for the join in merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe df1, df2

df1.columns

```
['id','a','b']
```

df2.columns

```
['id','ab','cd','ab_test','mn_test']
```

Expected out column is `['id','a','b','ab_test','mn_test']`

- How to get the all the columns from df1, and columns which contain `test` in the column name

  pseudocode > pd.merge(df1,df2,how='id')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) one the second dataframe to keep the columns of interest:

```
df1.merge(df2.filter(regex=r'^id$|test'), on='id')
```

Or similarly through bitwise operations:

```
df1.merge(df2.loc[:,(df2.columns=='id')|df2.columns.str.contains('test')], on='id')
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','ab','cd','ab_test','mn_test'])

df1.merge(df2.filter(regex=r'^id$|test'), on='id').columns
# Index(['a', 'b', 'id', 'ab_test', 'mn_test'], dtype='object')
```